# How to export WPF MS Chart to PNG

Tags: c#, mschart

I have a problem with chart export. I´m using MS Chart (System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit)

I can create graph, but cannot export/save to image. I sae somewhere method chart.SaveImage(...), but I can find it.

There is chart definition:

```
<DVC:Chart Name="mcChart" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="2,2,2,2" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" DockPanel.Dock="Left" MinWidth="200" />
```

and here a picture what I see when I call chart from C#, there is no SaveImage:

[image]

Please can you somebody help me? Am I missing some extension?
Thaks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like there's nothing built in.

There's [a post on the MSDN Forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/009bdcdc-f845-4618-ac97-7e3495969bd1/) that gives a solution. You have to create a [`RenderTargetBitmap`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.rendertargetbitmap.aspx) and use that:

```
RenderTargetBitmap renderBitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap(
    (int)chart1.ActualWidth,
    (int)chart1.ActualHeight,
    96d,
    96d,
    PixelFormats.Pbgra32);

renderBitmap.Render(chart1);
```

Comment: what if the chart is not instantiated in the view? I mean is there a way to create the image without creating the chart in the window? I've tried using the code above but image is empty

Answer (score 0):

To me it seems that for you it's enough to use

```
EditCopy()
```

method to save an image of the chart into a clipboard and after use C# clipboard to get  data from it.